# Make biblatex treat different author names as same author in text citations

Tags: biblatex, citing

Some guy has written a few books, but he is inconsistent from book to book when it comes to including and/or abbreviating his middle name. When I cite this author in the text, I would like `biblatex` to treat all different versions of his name as the same author. I can enforce this for the sorting in the bibliography with `sortname`, but what do I do to enforce this for text citations?

The following example illustrates how the text citation treats "Paul J[ohn] Smith" as a different author from "Paul John Smith" and "Paul Smith". The first citation should appear as (Smith 2002), and the second citation should appear as (2001a, 2001b, 2002).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        dashed = false,
        sorting = nyt,
        sortcites = false,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{smith2001a,
    AUTHOR = "Paul John Smith",
    TITLE = "My first book",  
    YEAR = "2001"}

@BOOK{smith2001b,
    AUTHOR = "Paul Smith",
    TITLE = "My second book",  
    YEAR = "2001",
    SORTNAME = "Paul John Smith"}

@BOOK{smith2002,
    AUTHOR = "Paul J[ohn] Smith",
    TITLE = "My third book",  
    YEAR = "2002",
    SORTNAME = "Paul John Smith"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Some clever guy said that \parencite{smith2002}.
In fact, Paul Smith has talked about this several times \parencite*{smith2001a,smith2001b,smith2002}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to verify the premise: Paul Smith, Paul J. Smith, and Paul John Smith are indeed one and the same person, right? It's just that this author isn't all that punctilious about always providing his middle name (or even the middle initial) in every publication, right?

Comment: You can put a consistent name for Paul Smith in the `shortauthor` field, as discussed in [this previous post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37857/4483).

Comment: See last example in section 4.5.2 in the biblatex manual. The sourcemap feature is designed to help with this.

Comment: @PLK This last example in 4.5.2, I add that to the file ``biber.conf``? Anywhere in that file? Could you or someone provide a working example for my example above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is now a biblatex macro interface to the sourcemapping feature, you can put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Paul\s+(?:J\S+\s+)?Smith}, final]
       \step[fieldset=shortauthor, fieldvalue={Smith, Paul John}]
       \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue={Smith, Paul John}]
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to tune the regular expression, I made it quite specific so as not to catch anything it shouldn't.

Comment: I added this to my preamble, but I got this error when I compiled: ``! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@tempf ...="author" map\string _match="Paul\s 
                                                  +J\S +\s +Smith" map\strin...
l.40 }``

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot the `\regexp{}` wrapper - fixed now.

Comment: Great. I especially like the fact that I can put this in the preamble of my document instead of having to mess with biber's config files.

Comment: The biber config file route is useful if you want such mappings to apply to all documents, not just the current one.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to show how PLK's solution above does the trick in practice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        dashed = false,
        sorting = nyt,
        sortcites = false,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{smith2001a,
    AUTHOR = "Paul John Smith",
    TITLE = "My first book",  
    YEAR = "2001"}

@BOOK{smith2001b,
    AUTHOR = "Paul Smith",
    TITLE = "My second book",  
    YEAR = "2001",
    SORTNAME = "Paul John Smith"}

@BOOK{smith2002,
    AUTHOR = "Paul J[ohn] Smith",
    TITLE = "My third book",  
    YEAR = "2002",
    SORTNAME = "Paul John Smith"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{Paul\s+(?:J\S+\s+)?Smith}, final]
       \step[fieldset=shortauthor, fieldvalue={Smith, Paul John}]
       \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue={Smith, Paul John}]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Some clever guy said that \parencite{smith2002}.
In fact, Paul Smith has talked about this several times \parencite*{smith2001a,smith2001b,smith2002}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]