# Having trouble enabling ligatures with HF&J's Mercury Text OpenType font

Tags: fontspec, ligatures, opentype, hoefler, fontforge

I'm sure [this font](http://www.typography.com/fonts/mercury-text/characters/) supports ligatures, but I can't get them to show up.

Example with Roboto for comparison:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont[
  ExternalLocation,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures=Common
]{Roboto}

roboto fight flight has ligatures

\setmainfont[
  ExternalLocation,
  Extension=.otf,
  Ligatures=Common
]{Mercury-TextG4Roman}

mercury fight flight no ligatures

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

The list of ligatures on HF&J's site lists `fi`:

[image: ligature list]

And charmap in Windows shows that character in that font:

[image: character map]

**Update**:

Output of `otfinfo`:

[image: otfinfo]

**Update 2**:

Changed to LuaLatex, added a features file:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}}

\begin{filecontents*}{mercury.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
# Ligatures
feature liga {
    sub \f \i by \fi;
    sub \f \l by \fl;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont[
  ExternalLocation,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures=Common
]{Roboto}

roboto fight flight has ligatures

\setmainfont[
  FeatureFile=mercury.fea,
  ExternalLocation,
  Extension=.otf,
  Ligatures=Common
]{Mercury-TextG4Roman}

mercury fight flight no ligatures

\end{document}
```

And ligatures show:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Since the font is commercial, I can't try this myself. What does `otfinfo -f <font filename>` give you? In particular, does it include the line `liga    Standard Ligatures`. For comparison, the output from `otfinfo -f Roboto-Regular.ttf` does include this line. This will determine whether or not the option you are trying to enable is supported. If not, all is not necessarily lost but the command's output will tell us more.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}` with `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}}`?

Comment: re Mico: same result. The `fl` and `fi` aren't ligatures.

Comment: Their website is hopeless. Not only do they not tell you what features the fonts support, but their online preview feature does not enable even common ligatures for fonts which I am damn sure have them. (I would be astonished if Hoefler does not support ligatures at this point, for example.)

Comment: Can you try the `otfinfo` command? That will tell us if the font supports any feature sets at all and, if so, which ones.

Comment: Hmm, `otfinfo -f` lists only `kern` on that file (and for `HoeflerText-Roman.otf` as well)

Comment: Despite my weakness for fonts, I’ve never bought from that designer because, as cfr notes, the website gives too little information.  So I’m working in the dark, but it may be that the font contains ligatures yet doesn’t define a feature for them.  In that case, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142605/7883 would be relevant.

Comment: This essentially means that the opentype fonts have not been constructed as required. The fonts may include the required glyphs, but that's it. They do not contain the settings which make it straightforward to use those glyphs as properly designed fonts do. It is more-or-less like having postscript type1 fonts which simply could not include this information because they are a much simpler format. For an explanation see [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152714/possible-to-use-mnsymbol-with-luatex/166185#166185).

Comment: OK. I finally realised what is probably going on. Hoefler Text almost certainly does contain support for automatic insertion of ligatures. However, it probably provides that information in the form of AAT features. Only Macs can use these. Moreover, I am not sure that LuaTeX/XeTeX still supports them even on Macs. (At least one of them used to do so. ConTeXt certainly did so as well.) At least in the case of Hoefler, this is because the truetype versions were created for Apple originally. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoefler_Text. I have no idea about Mercury.

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198061/differences-regarding-kerning-and-ligaturing-when-using-the-mactex2013-and-macte/209709#209709) for more information and changes to `fontspec`.

Comment: In your MWE, you load `Mercury-TextG4Roman`, but when you run `otfinfo`, you're looking into `Mercury-TextG1Roman`, i.e. not the same font.

Comment: @Thérèse I've never come across a commercial foundry for fonts that tells me _exactly_ what glyphs and OpenType features a font has (or what glyphs are activated by what features). That's the main reason why I don't buy any fonts at all. Commercial fonts are primarily meant for designers and novel writers who rarely need anything outside of `a-z, A-Z` in an upright font.

Comment: @Sverre Well... Apple certainly used them as a marketing feature - especially the AAT configuration in Hoefler, which was something of a flagship font. This isn't selling you a font on its own, I know, but it was part of the product they were selling.

Comment: @Sverre Some foundries provide PDF specimens that show the entire character set and explain the effect of the OpenType features, and some commercial fonts serve special scholarly needs such as proper transcription of unusual languages.  You just have to be careful where you buy fonts and have a clear understanding of your needs.

Comment: @Thérèse [Part 1] The best I have come across are foundries which will show you all the glyphs of a font within the Unicode range (but I've never seen a foundry tell what's in the unencoded space, which is where some niceties are hidden), and what OpenType features the font has (without specifying in any _detail_ which effects those features have on the font). As an example, see the [foundry](http://www.fonts.com) for the Adobe fonts, which are probably the best commercial fonts out there. The information for the [Minion Pro](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/minion/regular) fonts, ...

Comment: @Thérèse [Part 2] for example, will not tell you that the OpenType feature `liga` will activate a ligature for `Th`. I consider such information quite important, especially when the `Th` ligature isn't considered "standard" by anyone outside of Adobe. (Since I am myself a scholar of linguistics and philology, the best fonts I can think of are the [SIL fonts](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=SILFontList), [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net), and [Brill](http://www.brill.com/about/brill-fonts), all free).

Comment: @Sverre Adobe is not a foundry I consider generous with its information. But discussion of the relative merits of free and commercial fonts doesn’t belong here; sites like typophile.com already have threads on the subject to which you may contribute if you wish. It seems unfair to condemn a whole industry here, where there’s no room for an adequate defense. (And no, I’m not connected to the industry.)

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation. It's also ok to demonstrate with a separate answer that the accepted answer indeed works (I've [done that myself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69045/9077)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With kind help from @cfr, you've established that:

- The font does contain ligature glyphs.
- `fontspec` can't make use of AAT ligature information even if it's available.
- The font omits OpenType feature data necessary for automatic ligature support.

So what can you do? You can either add the missing mapping data to the font,
or create an external OpenType feature file (supported by LuaTeX only) and tell fontspec to use it. Neither is difficult.

### Adding Opentype `liga` Tables Using FontForge

**Note:** Consult the licensing terms for your font first, etc'.

1. Open up the font file in fontforge.
2. Open up The `Element->Font Info` dialog from the menu:
   [image: Font Info Dialog]
   The listed entries correspond to various OpenType "features", the one
   you want is named "Standard ligatures" in the list and termed the `liga`
   feature in the spec and the output of `otfinfo` and you already know it's
   missing from your font, so we need to create the table first, then populate it with the missing data.
3. Hit the "Add Lookup" button and select the type as "standard ligatures".
4. Hit the "Add Subtable" button to create the actual mapping table. double click on the new subtable entry to open its editor view.
5. You should now see the edito dialogue where you setup mappings between character sequences and ligature glyphs:
   [image: Ligature subtable editor]
   Use the "populate" button to have FontForge deduce the ligatures supported by the font and automaticaly create entries for you. Depending on the font you may need to edit/add entries manually as well. The left-hand column contains the glyph name for the ligature, while the right-hand column contains the individual characters, seperated by spaces.
6. When done, hit `Ok` twice to go back to the main window again.
7. Save the updated font file with `File->Generate Fonts`, making sure the type dropbox is set to `OpenType(CFF)`. Beware that the generated font carries the same internal font name as the original (though easy to change), so you must either overwrite the original (remember to backup) in order to avoid loading the old version, or you should specify the font file's path explicitly when loading it with `fontspec`.
8. You're done.

### Adding Opentype `liga` Tables Using An OpenType Feature File (LuaTeX only)

The `fontspec` manual has a [section](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf#page=37) on feature files (with a link to the [specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic%20feature%20file%20syntax.html)) and it includes an example that shows precisely what you're after, e.g. how to to define ligature mappings. So you need only create the feature file and then make use of the `FeatureFile` option to tell `fontspec` to load it:

**File:** another_league.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Alternatively, place this in a `mercury.fea` file in the same directory
\begin{filecontents*}{mercury.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;
# Ligatures
feature liga {
    sub \f \i by \fi;
    sub \f \l by \fl;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}
    
\setmainfont[
FeatureFile=mercury.fea,
%Ligatures={Common} % on by default
]{Mercury-TextG4Roman}

\begin{document}
    fi \symbol{"FB01} 
    
    fl \symbol{"FB02} 
\end{document}
```

This example assumes the ligature glyphs exist at their unicode standard
location and includes them directly by glyph number for comparison purposes. YMMV.

**Edit:** Beware that `fontspec` doesn't stop with an error if there are problems with the `FeatureFile` option. Mistyping a path, syntax errors in the file, or using an engine other than `LuaTeX` will quietly cause it to ignore the feature file.

Comment: I added a fontspec feature file and it worked. Thanks to you and @cfr.