# How can I properly force an author name in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have two issues with the authors names, and I think both of them can be solved by the same answer.

I read somewhere that I should use braces ("{" and "}") in order to explicitly choose what author name `biblatex` should treat as the last name, or the name that is used for such author. Therefore, all my authors are declared like the following examples:

```
@Article{article1,
  title = {{T}itle of the {A}rticle {N}umber 1},
  author = {John Smith {Doe} and Fulano Ciclano da {Silva}},
  year = {1966},
  ...
}

@Article{article2,
  title = {{A}wesome {T}itle of {A}rticle {N}umber 2},
  author = {Jonathan Lee {Kriggs} Junior and Someone {Else} and Pedro Paulo Costa {Silva}},
  year = {2016},
  ...
}
```

This was supposed to eliminate what the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) defines as prefix names (like "da" in "Fulano Ciclano **da** Silva") and suffix names (like "Junior" in "Jonathan Lee Kriggs **Junior**".

My preamble uses the following `biblatex` command:

```
\usepackage[backend = biber, citestyle = authoryear, sorting = none, uniquename=mininit, maxnames=3, minnames=3, maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=3]{biblatex}
```

For the following text:

```
Some text is written about some article \parencite{article1} and some newer article \parencite{article2}.
```

According to the rule that should force  `biblatex` to use authors' name between braces, this should output:

> Some text is written about some article (Doe and Silva, 1966) and some
> newer article (Kriggs, Else and Silva, 2016).

Instead, this is the output I am getting:

> Some text is written about some article (Doe and Silva, 1966) and some
> newer article (Junior, Else and Costa Silva, 2016).

The prefix name thing is working ok ("**Fulano Ciclano da Silva**" is being cite as "**Silva**"; the prefix "**da**" is disregarded, as expected). On the other hand, the suffix name is being cited instead of the name indicated between braces ("**Jonathan Lee Kriggs Junior**" is being cited as "**Junior**", instead of "**Kriggs**").

Even worse than the suffix thing, the last author is cited by both his middle and last names ("**Pedro Paulo Costa {Silva}**" is "**Costa Silva**"). "Pedro Paulo" is a double name, like "Mark Anthony" or "John Paul". I don't know if that influences anything (I don't think so), but I chose this example to understand if it does. Also came to mind that maybe it is being displayed wrong because the suffix thing already breaks this citation (again, no high hopes).

**Is there a way to explicitly choose the name `biblatex` displays?**

Or maybe ignore last-positioned names that are suffixes and are written differently from what Biblatex expects (i.e. "Jonathan Lee Kriggs Junior" instead of "Kriggs, Jr., Jonathan Lee").
I would like to avoid fiddling with my bib file, since it has over a thousand references, plus it would be very weird to have all author names in a way, and only a couple authors organised differently throughout the file.

Comment: Braces on their own do not make Biber (or BibTeX) recognise anything as a family name. So `Jonathan Lee {Kriggs} Junior` is pretty much the same as `Jonathan Lee {Kriggs} Junior`. Curly braces stop Biber (and BibTeX) from breaking up names into given and family names (etc.), this is usually relevant for corporate (non-person) names: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### tl;dr

There are *some* ways to influence which (bit of a) name is displayed in which way in citations and the bibliography, but usually this only works properly if the name is specified correctly (according to the BibTeX rules) in the `.bib` file.

There is little point in trying to fix incorrect input in the `.bib` file by ad hoc modifications of the name format. And there is probably very little to be gained there anyway.

Braces only really help with what you want to do if they enclosing something containing a space.

---

### The full picture

[How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) explains how BibTeX and Biber parse names. Roughly speaking a name is separated into family name, given name, prefix ("von part") and suffix ("junior part"). You can choose how these name parts are arranged in the bibliography and citations, but  if you stick to the normal name input, you have only limited influence as to what bit of the name gets parsed as which name part.

With `biblatex` there are ways to override the names shown in the citations by means of the `shortauthor` field. `shortautor` is again parsed as a normal name field. So in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author      = {Anne Elk},
  shortauthor = {Barbara Zelk},
  title       = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year        = {1972},
  publisher   = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location    = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Zelk 1972)//Elk, Anne (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. London: Monthy & Co.]

the actual author name is `family=Elk, given=Anne,` but in citations `biblatex` uses `family=Zelk, given=Barbara,` and behaves accordingly. Of course this can be used with 'less' diverging examples than Elk/Zelk to force a particular output in citations for a complex name, see [Make biblatex treat different author names as same author in text citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68879/35864) or [Peerage titles in the author field in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147932/35864). Another common usage for this field is abbreviation of long corporate-type author names ([Biblatex: Abbreviating authoring organisations in citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47286/35864)).

If you use `biblatex` with Biber, you can use the extended name format to explicitly specify each bit of a name. This is useful if you want to override the normal parsing rules locally (see e.g. [Use only the last name as namepartfamily instead of everything after prefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308625/35864) and [Two or three letter initials in bibliography with Biblatex (again)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422938/35864)), but unless you declare new name parts and use them ([Bibliography according to icelandic system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287732/35864), [Bibtex/Biber: how to cite an author using Ethiopian conventions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313176/35864), [CJK Bibliography Problem, Biblatex-Chicago author-date style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390369/35864)) things will still have to fit into the four name part scheme, so you *usually* don't gain a lot over specifying the name in `<prefix> <family>, <suffix>, <given>` format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, giveninits]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  author    = {family=Doe Roe, given=Charles, given-i={Ch}},
  title     = {An Important Book},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{book1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Doe Roe 2012)//Doe Roe, Ch. (2012). An Important Book. Publisher.]

---

[How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864) does not mention it explicitly, but curly braces around a bit of a name that is separated with spaces from other bits does not make a relevant difference for the name parsing you are interested in. Curly braces are particularly relevant if you want to 'protect' names (or name parts) with spaces in them from being broken apart (see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)).

So

```
Fulano Ciclano da {Silva}
```

is pretty much the same as

```
Fulano Ciclano da Silva
```

when it comes to breaking up the name into different parts.
The difference is only the additional curly braces in the name part

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{un=0,uniquepart=base,hash=fa2fe34e8e6f02735fb558279b21902f}{%
       family={{Silva}},
       familyi={S\bibinitperiod},
       given={Fulano\bibnamedelima Ciclano},
       giveni={F\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim C\bibinitperiod},
       givenun=0,
       prefix={da},
       prefixi={d\bibinitperiod},
       prefixun=0}}%
  }
```

(there were some issues with initials generation with the excessive braces: [! Paragraph ended before \name was complete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414685/35864)) vs

```
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{un=0,uniquepart=base,hash=fa2fe34e8e6f02735fb558279b21902f}{%
       family={Silva},
       familyi={S\bibinitperiod},
       given={Fulano\bibnamedelima Ciclano},
       giveni={F\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim C\bibinitperiod},
       givenun=0,
       prefix={da},
       prefixi={d\bibinitperiod},
       prefixun=0}}%
  }
```

Assuming in *Fulano Ciclano da Silva* the *Fulano Ciclano* bit is the given name, the *da* the name prefix and *Silva* the family name, the input

```
Fulano Ciclano da Silva
```

is correct.

Hispanic names with two family names are not so simple, however, because BibTeX and Biber assume a person has one family name and not two. So if the name is actually `family=Ciclano da Silva, given=Fulano,` but is only cited as `Silva`, things are more tricky and you will probably have to resort to `shortauthor` or define new name parts that account for hispanic name customs.

---

For names with a *junior* or *senior* part, the only correct input is

```
von Last, Jr, First
```

so

```
Jonathan Lee Kriggs Junior
```

will not be parsed as expected, it must be given as

```
Kriggs, Junior, Jonathan Lee
```

I understand that it is annoying to go through your database to change this, but I'm afraid you will have to stick with the correct format if you want the names to be parsed correctly. In theory you could try some of the workarounds suggested above to force the desired output, but that is probably just as much (if not more) work and definitely not recommended.

---

I cannot reproduce the *Costa Silva* issue.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend = biber,
  citestyle = authoryear,
  sorting = none,
  uniquename=mininit,
  maxnames=3, minnames=3,
  maxbibnames=5, minbibnames=3,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{article1,
  title  = {Title of the Article Number 1},
  author = {John Smith {Doe} and Fulano Ciclano da {Silva}},
  year   = {1966},
}
@Article{article2,
  title  = {Awesome Title of Article Number 2},
  author = {Jonathan Lee {Kriggs} Junior and Someone {Else}
            and Pedro Paulo Costa {Silva}},
  year   = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text is written about some article \parencite{article1}
and some newer article \parencite{article2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Some text is written about some article (Doe and Silva 1966) and some newer article (Junior, Else and Silva 2016).]

for me, which is expected.

In general when first names pop up citations the option `uniquename` ([biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864)) is relevant. (A related option is `uniquelist`, which is usually the next thing people who don't like `uniquename` ask about: [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864)). But you evidently already know about this option and I don't think this option could explain *Costa Silva* popping up in the citation, because it would add given name initials or given names, which for `Pedro Paulo Costa {Silva}` would be *Pedro Paulo Costa* and not just *Costa*.

Comment: Very complete answer.
I ended up changing the name with Junior to the way Biblatex does its thing (thankfully, it was only one: my supervisor/advisor). Shame there isn't a simple way of choosing the right name. I will probably go over the whole bib file to fix all authors' names, the way they are set. Who knows what is the next thing that will break it again?

Comment: Also, even by fixing the "Junior" author, the "Costa Silva" stayed that way. I fixed it the same way, so ```Silva, Pedro Paulo Costa```. There were four authors in the article, three of which had Costa as one of the family names and their given names were all double names, all Brazilian (latin names, so generally two family names).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, they were, in order, Jonathan Lee Kriggs Junior (1st), John Paul Costa Doe (2nd), Mary Ann Levine Costa (3rd) and Pedro Paulo Costa Silva (4th). I figure Biblatex added "Costa" only for the last author because the second author had Costa in its middle name, but wasn't ambiguous just yet, as it was the first to have Costa, and not in its last name. Then, the 3rd author had Costa as its last name. Finally, the 4th guy also had Costa, but as its middle name again. Pretty one-in-a-million type of situation, but it was fixed by the right way of adding the authors.

Comment: @HWerneck On the risk of sounding like an idiot: There *is* a way of choosing the right name: Using the right input format. Software cannot always guess what we mean, it needs structured input according to its syntax rules. There definitely is value in having (fairly) simple, but general parsing rules that can be implemented easily and efficiently (keep in mind that BibTeX was written in the 1980s).

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the situation with the superfluous Costa (as demonstrated in the answer), but since it probably has to do `uniquename` and `uniquelist` it will be fairly context-dependent, so not easy to track down if we don't know your document. An additional Costa is definitely not what I would expect and might be considered a bug, if the input is correct, but I don't think I can investigate this with the information I have at the moment.

Comment: no problem. I am fixing the authors' names to fit the proper syntax, like you said. It is the best way, no doubt. I only hoped there was another way, since all authors' names were working until the "Junior" case. Maybe uniquename or uniquelist would fix the "Costa" situation, but it is already fixed by the right syntax.

Comment: When starting with latex, I didn't know which syntax would work for all cases. I found different ways of typing names, and chose the one that seemed less confuse. Then, the braces use fixed some issue I had back then (don't remember, probably hyphenated name). One thing let to another. I mean, at first, ```{Kriggs, Junior, Jonathan Lee and Silva, Pedro Paulo Costa},``` feels way more confuse then  ```{Jonathan Lee Kriggs Junior and Pedro Paulo Costa Silva},```. Multiple commas and "and" get messy on 5+ author articles. Anyways, I'm happy working up the solution. Thanks a lot for the help!